# Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_pdo_driver::where() in

Tags: codeigniter, pdo

I’m using PDO driver to access MySQL database. Everything is working OK on that part. My database.php looks like this:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = FALSE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1:3386';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mydatabase';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

I don’t use Active Record..

The problem occurred when I auto-loaded session library and set it to use database. I created table in my database, and on first visit to site, a record gets inserted into session table. No problem there.
An error occurs on subsequent visits to the site. I’m getting following:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_pdo_driver::where() in P:\Git\TengWebsite\system\libraries\Session.php on line 201
```

Comment: Let's keep guessing what line #201 is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set $active_record = TRUE;

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
```

**Note: that some CodeIgniter classes such as Sessions require Active Records be enabled to access certain functionality.**

its clearly stated here [CodeIgniter Doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/configuration.html)